# How to print sqlite.swift statement as SQL?

Tags: sql, swift, sqlite.swift

I'm trying to debug some sqlite.swift statements that aren't delivering the results I expect.

The documentation shows examples of SQL in comments.

```
for user in try db.prepare(users.select(id, email)) {
    print("id: \(user[id]), email: \(user[email])")
    // id: 1, email: alice@mac.com
}
// SELECT "id", "email" FROM "users"
```

How do I get the statement to print that SQL?

`print("\(users.select(id, email))")` does not give me SQL. Am I overlooking something in the documentation?

Comment: A quick glance at the source showed  that Statement objects have a .description variable and QueryType has an expression variable. I would try those. Though if you post the statement maybe someone can help with it too..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following command will print all SQL statements:

```
db.trace(print)
```

See https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#logging

Comment: That prints all statements. I'm trying to print one specific statement.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to see the SQL being executed then print(query.asSQL())

```
let query = dbTable
            .filter(dbSourceKey == Int64(minElement))
            .filter(dbTargetKey == Int64(maxElement))

print(query.asSQL())//Will show SQL statement
```

Comment: As of version 0.14.1 `asSQL()` is now internal, not public. You can instead use `query.description`.